# New rolling mean column which group by one column and find rolling mean of another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe df

| Date | Orders | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:00 | 20 | A |
| 1/1/2021 00:12:00 | 100 | B |
| 2/1/2021 00:00:00 | 24 | A |
| 2/1/2021 00:13:00 | 96 | B |
| ----- | --- | -- |
| 14/1/2021 | 34 | A |
| 14/1/2021 | 103 | B |

I want a new column 'Rolling mean' by taking the mean of orders for 2 weeks in such a way

| Date | Orders | Group | Rolling Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:00 | 20 | A | NA or 0 |
| 1/1/2021 00:12:00 | 100 | B | NA or 0 |
| 2/1/2021 00:00:00 | 24 | A | NA or 0 |
| 2/1/2021 00:13:00 | 96 | B | Na or 0 |
| ----- | --- | -- |  |
| 14/1/2021 00:00:00 | 34 | A | 29 |
| 14/1/2021 00:00:00 | 103 | B | 101 |

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
df['Rolling Mean'] = df['Orders'].rolling(window=pd.Timedelta(days=14)).mean()
```

Note that the `min_periods` argument in the `pd.rolling()` method takes an integer and doesn't handle time series easily, so you'll need to overwrite the first 14 days of the new Rolling Mean column with `np.nan` as a second step if you don't want there to be any values in there until there's at least 14 days to average. This can be achieved by:

```
# find integer number of time periods in first 14 days.
delay = len(df.loc[:(df.index[0]+pd.Timedelta(days=14))])

# set all means to `NaN` in those time steps.
df.iloc[:delay] = np.nan
```

This answer assumes the date column is your index column, and that you have `numpy` installed as `np` so you can call `np.nan`. Good luck!

Comment: @datalearner did the answer work for you? Let the community know by accepting or asking questions on it, and good luck!